# Why does the scaladoc say HashMap.toArray returns Array[A] instead of Array[(A,B)]?

Tags: scala, scaladoc

I was looking at the definition of `toArray` for hashmaps :

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.HashMap

It has

```
toArray: Array[A]
def toArray[B >: (A, B)](implicit arg0: ClassTag[B]): Array[B]
```

I don't quite understand this - the first bit says you get an Array[A], but the second part says you get Array[B]? Neither of these are what I expect - Array[(A,B)]

When I check it myself :

```
scala> val x = scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String, Int]()
x: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap[String,Int] = Map()

scala> x.put("8", 7)
res0: Option[Int] = None

scala> x foreach println
(8,7)

scala> x.toArray
res2: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((8,7))
```

why isn't it like toList?

```
toList: scala.List[(A, B)]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The scaladoc has all kinds of subtle bugs. The problem here is that you are seeing the "simplified" version of the method signature (meant as a way to convey the essential part of the signature and hide things such as `CanBuildFrom` in `map`/`flatMap` methods, which are really an implementation detail).
The simplification got a little awry here, and does not seem to make much sense.
If you click on the "full signature" link, you'll see that the real signature looks like:

```
def toArray[B >: (A, B)](implicit arg0: ClassTag[B]): Array[B]
```

In fact this is still wrong, as we certainly cannot have a type B where B >: (A, B). It should be more like    :

```
def toArray[C >: (A, B)](implicit arg0: ClassTag[C]): Array[C]
```

The problem is that there are actually two `B`s: the first one comes from the `HashMap` class declaration itself (`HashMap[A, +B]`) while the other one comes from the methods `toArray` defined in its base class 
`TraversableOnce` (`def toArray[B >: A](implicit arg0: ClassTag[B]): Array[B]`). It just happens that the scaladoc generator failed to dedup the two instances of `B`

Answer (score 2):

The API you see in the the Scaladoc of `toArray`:

```
def toArray[B >: (A, B)](implicit arg0: ClassTag[B]): Array[B]
```

Is equivalent to:

```
def toArray[C >: (A, B)](implicit arg0: ClassTag[C]): Array[C]
```

The choice of the type variable `B` is indeed unfortunate (and maybe even a Scaladoc bug, I'm not sure if you are allowed to write that).

It basically means you'll get an array of the most specific supertype of `(A,B)` **for which a `ClassTag` is available**. The `ClassTag` is required in order to create the `Array`.

This basically means that if at compile-time, the-run time type of the `Map` you are converting is fully known, you will get a `Array[(A,B)]`. However, if you have up-casted your `Map` somewhere, the run-time type of the resulting `Array` will depend on the up-casted type, and not on the runtime type. This **is** different behavior than `toList` and due to the JVMs restrictions on how native arrays can be created.

Answer (score 1):

The Scaladoc is just wrong because it inherits `toArray` from `TraversableOnce`, where the type of the collection is `A` and the return value is `B`.  The `Array[A]` thing is left over from `TraversableOnce` where `A` is whatever `TraversableOnce` is traversing (in this case, actually `(A,B)` for a different definition of `A` and `B`); and although it fills the `(A,B)` in properly in the long form, it still uses `B` as the new return variable instead of a different letter like `C`.

Kind of confusing!  It actually should read

```
def toArray[C >: (A,B)](...[C]): Array[C]
```

and the short form should be

```
toArray: Array[(A,B)]
```

just like you expect.